# Date convert to Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to convert javascript Date to highstock data?
This is array from highstock examples:

```
[
/* Nov 2008 */
[1227830400000,13.24],
/* Dec 2008 */
[1228089600000,12.70],
[1228176000000,13.21],
[1228262400000,13.70],
[1228348800000,13.06],
[1228435200000,13.43],
]
```

this is my function witch should return array with the same type :

```
function my_convert(data)
        {
            var arr = []
            data.forEach(function (i) {
                var my_date = new  Date(parseInt(i.Index.substr(6)))
                arr.push([ my_date, i.Value])
            })
            return arr
        }
```

my_date has a type Date. How to convert it into a data type that is needed Highstok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast it to Number.

```
arr.push([ Number(my_date), i.Value]);
```

or just

```
arr.push([ +my_date, i.Value])
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lvf7y04/1/